# trouble finding $a$ and $r$ for geometric series formula

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac1{2^n} $

Somehow this gives $a = \frac12$, $r = \frac12$ to put into the formula $\sum_{n=1}^\infty ar^{n-1}$.

whats a general method (if any) for finding $a$ and $r$ in the geometric series formula?

i know that if you put a series in the form $\sum_{n=1}^\infty  ar^{n-1} $ you can find if it is divergent (if $|r| \ge 1$) or convergent (if $|r| < 1$) with the sum being $\frac{a}{1-r}$. I am not quite sure however how to obtain $a$ and $r$ from a series and put it into the general form of the geometric series.

my question is HOW do i find the values $a$ and $r$

Comment: Please make the question clear.

Comment: im not sure how to make it more clear... the formula is  summation[a*r^(n-1)] and a = 1/2, r = 1/2, how can I get a and r to be those values from my original equation Summation[ 1/(2^n)] ?

Comment: Go through this http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: ok, thank you. .

Comment: Question is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well this is the simple answer to the simple question.

it appears from further research that $a$ is simply the first evaluation of the series and $r$ is $\frac{a_2}{a_1}$. which makes $a_1 = \frac12, a_2 = \frac14,$ so $\frac{a_2}{a_1} = \frac12$, therefor $r = \frac12$.

nowwwww I see, I was dividing $a_1$ by $a_2$, not the other way around, to get $2$ earlier.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information.  The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: but this WAS the complete answer to my actual QUESTION

Answer (score 2):

We know, $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} ar^{k-1}=  a\dfrac{1-r^{n}}{1-r}$.

Now, $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty  \dfrac1{2^k}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n  \dfrac1{2^k}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n  \left(\dfrac12\right)\cdot{\left(\dfrac1{2}\right)}^{k-1}$.

This is in the form of the above formula with $a=\dfrac12$ and $r=\dfrac12$. So the expression becomes,

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac12\dfrac{1-\left(\frac12\right)^{n}}{1-\frac12}
=\lim_{n\to\infty} 1-\left(\frac12\right)^n=1.$

---

If we instead know,  $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} ar^{k-1}=\dfrac{a}{1-r}$ for $|r|<1$,

Then again,

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty  \dfrac1{2^k}=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty  \left(\dfrac12\right)\left(\dfrac12\right)^{k-1}$

which is in the form of the preceding formula with $a=\frac12$ and $r=\frac12$ (and $|r|<1$).

Comment: yes, i did not know what "we know" in the first line...

Comment: @mathisatroll That's the formula for the sum of a geometric series.

Comment: actually im still not quite clear on how you acquire 1/2 for a and r in the first place.

Comment: i knew the formula as the left hand side of the first line, but no where in the book did it say anything about the right hand side.

Comment: @mathisatroll Could you tell me precisely what you know of the sum of a geometric series? I'm not sure where your confusion lies.

Comment: i know that if you put a series in the form $\sum_{n=1}^\infty  ar^{n-1} $  you can find if it is divergent (if |r| >= 1) or convergent (if |r| < 1) with the sum being a/(1-r). I am not quite sure however how to obtain a and r from a series and put it into the general form of the geometric series.

Comment: @mathisatroll I've edited my answer.

Comment: but how did you figure out to plug in 1/2 to a and r? did you just take the equation and knock of the "k" power?

Comment: @mathisatroll The known formula is an identity i.e. it is true for all values of $a$ and $r$ (as long as $|r|<1$).
If you compare this formula with $\sum_{k=1}^\infty  \left(\frac12\right)\left(\frac12\right)^{k-1}$, it should be clear that the left-hand side of this formula exactly matches this expression if we set $a=0.5$ and $r=0.5$. Since $|r|<1$, we can conclude that the expression equals $\frac{0.5}{1-0.5}=1$. Does this clarify your doubts?

Comment: i dont have a doubt those two expressions are equal, my question is HOW do i find the values "a" and "r" to BEGIN with.

Answer (score 1):

The number $r$ is the ratio of two consecutive terms in $\sum_{n=1}^\infty ar^{n-1}$. That is, we have
$$r=\frac{ar^n}{ar^{n-1}}.$$
And when you have $r$, you should be able to get $a$.

NOTE: If you have a series $\sum b_n$ and the ratio $\frac{b_n}{b_{n-1}}$ depends on $n$, then you know that your series is NOT geometric.

Comment: im still confused on how you get "r" to begin with.. seeing as your formula has "r" = (an expression with r in it as well). i tried taking the ratio of the first two terms of the series 1/(2^n) but that left me with 2, not 1/2..

Comment: @mathisatroll  you have to take the ratio in the right order: $(1/2^n)/(1/2^{n-1})=1/2$.

Comment: i just wrote that below 4 hours ago.